# Using .Filter When the Filter Criteria are in Pre-existing String (TypeScript/Node.js)

Tags: arrays, node.js, typescript, filter, eval

I'm trying to process an array of JSON objects that have various common attributes, filtering each array entry on one or more of those attributes.

Normally, I'd just do it something like this:

```
let filteredResultsArray = originalArray.filter((obj) => {
   return obj.attribute1 <= 3 && obj.attribute2 > 0 && obj.attribute3 === 10;
});
```

My problem is that the filter parameters (the part after "return" in the code above) are highly variable (and unpredictable) from run to run, so I can't hard-code them in the filter. I compute them on the fly and store the whole thing in a string in my code. For example, on one run it might be:

```
myAttributeString = "obj.attribute1 <= 3 && obj.attribute2 > 0 && obj.attribute3 === 10";
```

I've tried doing this:

```
let filteredResultsArray = originalArray.filter((obj) => {
       return myAttributeString;
    });
```

That's failing to filter anything. Apparently `.filter()` is not properly interpreting what I've stored in `myAttributeString` as filter criteria.

I have a sneaking suspicion that `eval(myAttributeString)` might be one way to pull this off, but unfortunately I'm working on a team where we've got tslint set to disallow the use of `eval()`, so that's not an option.

Anybody have an idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

When you "compute them on the fly", instead of creating a *string*, create a *callback function* that you can then pass to `filter`. For example, instead of

```
const myAttributeString = "obj.attribute1 <= 3 && obj.attribute2 > 0 && obj.attribute3 === 10";
```

do

```
const filterCallback = obj => obj.attribute1 <= 3 && obj.attribute2 > 0 && obj.attribute3 === 10
```

Then, later, when the appropriate time comes to `.filter`, simply pass that as the callback:

```
const filteredResultsArray = originalArray.filter(filterCallback);
```

If you can't pass functions around, another option would be to build an array of conditions, for example

```
[
  {
    prop: "attribute1",
    constraint: "<=",
    value: 3
  },
  {
    prop: "attribute2",
    constraint: ">",
    value: 0
  },
  // ...
]
```

and then turn the object into the `filter` function needed.

Comment: I misspoke somewhat in the original question (for simplicity). Unfortunately, the "computed on the fly" string is provided to me (I don't create it in my piece of the code), so I'm expected to work with it.  I really like your first suggestion, but given that string I'm provided, I'm faced with the same challenge: how do I evaluate it and insert it into 'code' const filterCallback ? BTW, I temporarily defeated tslint and confirmed that eval() definitely works with my original approach, but I can't use it for the final solution (of course).

Comment: What does the `myAttributeString` look like? For example, is it always in the form of 
`obj.<someattribute> <somecomparator> <somevalue>` joined by `&&`s?

Comment: No, nothing that simple. It can be one term (of the form ===, !==, attribute.includes(), etc. etc.) all the way up to 9 such terms, joined with either && or ||. It can be composed of strictly numerical comparisons, string comparisons, or a combination of the two (and the exact nature of each instance is entirely unpredictable).

Comment: Here's an example of one of the more complicated strings I've seen so far:   `row.Average > 89.9 && row.Pass > 10 && row.Fail < 2 && row.Type === "C" && row.ID.startsWith("5") === false && row.Inspector.includes(" ") === false;`

Answer (score 0):

****************************************UPDATE******************************

As I suspected, `eval()` did work, but since I can't use it in my delivered code, and thanks to CertainPerformance's suggestion (which put my thinking on the right track) as well as the Node.js documentation site (via a lucky Google search), I was able to find a workaround using the `vm` module:

```
import * as vm from "vm";

let filteredResultsArray = originalArray.filter(
    vm.runInThisContext("(obj) => {
        return " + myAttributeString + ";}"));
```

Case closed.